# How to put 3d marker on map using Cesium js?

Tags: 3d, layer, marker, cesiumjs

I have used below code :

```
var entitylable = viewer.entities.add({  
    label: {  
        show: true,  
        showBackground: true,  
        font: '20px monospace',  
        fillColor: Cesium.Color.GHOSTWHITE,  
        horizontalOrigin: Cesium.HorizontalOrigin.LEFT,  
        verticalOrigin: Cesium.VerticalOrigin.BOTTOM,  
        pixelOffset: new Cesium.Cartesian2(0, -25),  
        disableDepthTestDistance: Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY  
    },  
    //position: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromRadians(lon, lat),  
    model: {  
        uri: "@Url.Content("~/Images/3dCesium_Man.glb")"              
    }  
});   
 var position = Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(lon + (radius * 1.5 * Math.cos(radians)), lat + (radius * Math.sin(radians)), 0);
entity.position = position;
```

Also Here marker is supposed to move on map with time. As I am working on live tracking system.  I am new developer to CesiumJS.

Or simply let me know how can I put 3d Marker on 3d MAP using Cesium?

Comment: What do you mean by 3D marker?  I see you're using a 3D model, with what looks like a Razor template, does that model show up for you?  You also have a label but there's no label text, did you want a label on it?  Do you want a point or icon type marker associated with it?

Comment: Also your `position` is commented out, of course you will need a valid `position` for an entity to show up on the globe.

Comment: yes,I want icon type marker on map.It could be ** .glb**  image .No i don't want lable on it.Here model is of one of the floor of building.I have used Canvas and get layer of 3d MAP on it. I have added position code in above lines which I am using .This will be dynamic as it is live tracking system . @emackey.